# How to read in a string with spaces in C++ without using getline

Tags: c++

my input file looks like this :
S New York 25 76 49

i want to read them where S is a character and New York is either a string or a cstring and the other 3 are integers. My problem is reading in New York i cant use getline since the 3 integers come after it and not in a new line. What can i do?

Comment: I recommend getline, but you'll need to search and or puzzle over how 'find' the state-start-index and the state-end-index.  Hmm, looks like state-start is index 2?  And maybe the state-end-index is the index of the blank before the 3rd integer from the end (in this case 25).  Fun

Comment: Use `getline`. Read into a string and pull the parts you need out of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other option is simply to read a character at a time and as long as the character `isalpha()` or `isspace()` followed by another `isalpha()`, store the character in your string. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    char c, last = 0;
    string s;

    while (cin.get(c)) {        /* read a character at a time */
        /* if last is alpha or (last is space and current is alpha) */
        if (last && (isalpha(last) || (isspace(last) && isalpha(c))))
            s.push_back(last);  /* add char to string */
        last = c;               /* set last to current */
    }

    cout << "'" << s << "'\n";
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "S New York 25 76 49" | ./bin/cinget
'S New York'
```

It may not be as elegant as a regex, but you can always parse what you need simply by walking through each character of input and picking out what you need.

Comment: Thanks, i was having trouble trying to get regex to work

Comment: Sure, glad to help. You can even rework the `if` to preserve multiple whitespace or compress multiple spaces to 1, etc.. There is nothing you can't parse simply by "walking-down-a-string" picking out what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Regular Expressions to parse the input. Added to the standard library in C++ 11 [<regex> C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)

More details on wikipedia: [Regular Expressions in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Regular_expressions)